How can I close my own question with reference to another post?
I’ve asked a question on Stack Overflow. But somehow I found an answer from some other post. What should I do now?

If you’ve got the 15 rep required to flag, you can flag your own post as a duplicate, and then select the other post.  Being the author of your post, you’ll get a notification that your post is possibly a duplicate;  select Yes, and Submit.  This is will close your post.
If you haven’t unlocked the privilege to make regular flags, then you should still be able to raise a custom In need of Moderator intervention flag.  If you explain that your question is a duplicate and link to the other post, this should work, but — especially larger sites like Stack Overflow — this will probably take some time to be handled.

Not sure all mods would consider this as something worth custom flagging, so there's a chance such a flag would be rejected. But overall that is indeed the best way to get it closed with less than 15 rep.

Also the "being the author this will automatically close" is wrong, though there is a pending feature request asking to change it. (TL;DR: It does not close, OP still has to click another button to actually close.)

@SathyapriyaMuthukrishnan just to confirm, when you flagged your own question as duplicate, did it automatically close it as duplicate? Or did you get a such a banner?

Note that "In need of moderator intervention" flags like these are almost surely going to be declined on Stack Overflow. Not sure about other sites.

@blackgreen I don’t know why that would be declined. Can you post another option/suggestion for SO users without the rep required to flag their own post?

It would be declined because SO moderators don't necessarily have the technical expertise to assess if the post is actually a duplicate as the flagger claims. Closures like these are usually left to the community to sort out, or the OP, as the first part of your answer suggests, once they have enough reputation. Surely there is a chance that a given flag gets handled by a moderator with relevant subject-matter expertise, but with 25 moderators on SO, that's not a bet we tend to encourage.

@ShadowWizard I got a banner and I ve closed it again like 'that post helped me to resolve the issue'

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79254428/400-bad-request-in-jquery-ajax this is the question I ve asked.

And it is not mentioned like "i" flagged my own post anywhere!

@SathyapriyaMuthukrishnan thanks, so nothing changed. The closure by "Community" is a known issue, and not considered a bug by Stack Overflow. However, you might see your flag in your flag summary.

Oh, ok got it @ShadowWizard thanks.
